# How to restrict Joins across Schemas in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

We want to have schemas/database for each functionality on our MySQL Server; so that if load on DB grows; we can move that particular schema to independent server anyday.

How to restrict Joins across Schemas in MySQL ?

Comment: You can have different MySQL users assigned for each of the schema

Comment: I would experiment with [Federated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html) so that your assumed performance expectations are realistic